# Understanding a lemma about prime numbers and divisors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

In the [MCS book from MIT](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf) (p. 170) they give the following lemma:

> For any prime $p$ and any positive integers $n,x_1, x_2, \ldots,  x_n$, if $p \mid x_1\cdot x_2\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n$,
> then $p\mid x_i$ for some $1\le i\le n$.

I have two questions about this lemma though...

(1) What even is the point of it? Consider the prime $p = 7$. $p$ only divides $7$ and $1$, so the if statement doesn't even really apply to primes $p$ unless you write $7 = 7 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$ or something similar, which brings me to (2)

(2) Why restrict it to primes $p$? It seems infinitely more useful to talk about composite numbers.

Comment: You seem to be confused in point (1). $p=7$ means that $p \mid 7,14,21,...$. and so on. $p$ does **not** divide $1$, although it does divide $0$.

Comment: When one says, e.g, "$7$ divides $n$" that means that $n$ is a multiple of $7$.  Thus your claim that "$p=7, p$ only divides $7$ and $1$". is false.  $7$ divides infinitely many integers.  I think you are confusing "$a$ divides $b$" with "$a$ is divisible by $b$".

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comments! I feel like I did indeed mix them up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very often, that is the definition of a prime number. This is not always true for composites. For example, $4 | 2 \cdot 2$ but $4 \nmid 2$.

In your question, I think you confused "for all" and "for some". The statement says that $p | x_i$ *for some i*. In your example, $p | 7$ so that is enough.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I think I got divides notation mixed up as well. I thought "a divides b" means that $a = bk$ for some $k$, when it actually means $b = ka$ for some $k$

Answer (score 0):

Composite numbers don't fulfill that condition. For example, $\;6\,\mid 3\cdot4\;$,  yet $\;6\nmid 3\;$ and $\;6\nmid 4\;$ ...